# Multiplying two randomly generated number until a condition is met

Tags: c#, while-loop

I'm trying to make a program that multiplies two randomly generated numbers. 
It should run the multiplication process until the answer is more than 269.

I think there's something wrong with my while loop. When I run the program it keep multiplying the same numbers but the answer is keep increasing until it reaches 268 and then the program is terminated.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random randomelyGeneratedNumbers = new Random();
            int num1 = randomelyGeneratedNumbers.Next(1, 25);
            int num2 = randomelyGeneratedNumbers.Next(1, 9);
            int answer = num1 * num2;
            //  Console.WriteLine(num1+" x "+num2+" is : "+answer);

            while(answer < 269)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1+" x "+num2+" is : "+answer);
                answer++;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to keep regenerating random numbers and knowing their product, you need to do those things *inside* the loop. Not just once.

Comment: You might also do some maths and observe that 269/9 is 29.9. Since 9 is the highest number that `num2` can be assigned, and 29.9 is greater than `num1` can be assigned, no combination of random numbers generated using *your specific options* will ever satisfy your problem.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever `.Next(1,9)` is from 1 - 8, so the max value `num2` can have is `8` and num1 `24` -> `24*8=192` < 269

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever does that mean that i should put the random generator for num1 and num2 within the while loop?

Comment: Yes.  Right now you are going through the loop 269 times since you are incrementing answer by one each time through the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random randomelyGeneratedNumbers = new Random();
    int answer = 0;
    while(answer < 269)
    {
        num1 = randomelyGeneratedNumbers.Next(1, 30);
        num2 = randomelyGeneratedNumbers.Next(1, 11);
        answer = num1 * num2;
        if (answer < 296) {
           Console.WriteLine(num1+" x "+num2+" is : "+answer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question , what if I want to know how many multiplications it took until the answer got bigger than 269 ? im pretty sure I gotta use a counter inside the while loop, im not sure how tho?

Comment: Just add another variable like counter. And increment it inside the loop. So when you get out of the loop, the counter has its last value